# How to Find Adjusted $R^2$ or $R^2$ from Lasso and Ridge regression model

Tags: r, regression, lasso, ridge-regression

How do I find the adjusted $R^2$ (or $r^2$) from Lasso and Ridge regression?

I used the glmnet package.  For instance if I have this code so far....

```
###LASSO 
library(glmnet)
attach(mtcars)
y=mtcars$mpg
    model=model.matrix(mpg~ . data=mtcars)
    lasso.reg=cv.glmnet(model, y, type.measure='mse', alpha=0)
    names(lasso.reg)
    mse=lasso.reg$cvm[lasso.reg$lambda == lasso.reg$lambda.min]
rmse = sqrt(mse)
```

Can someone show me the code that will give me the $R^2$ and the Adjusted $R^2$.  Sorry I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

The cross-validated estimate is essentially your adjusted $R^2$, estimated empirically. If you divide the mean square error by $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2$, which is almost the variance of y for large $n$, you'll get $1 - R^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The adjusted $R^2$ can be defined as

$$R_{adj}^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_{residuals}/df_{residuals}}{SS_{total}/df_{total}}$$

with $SS$ the sum of squares of residuals and the total sum of squares (relative to the mean), and $df$ the degrees of freedom.

This makes less sense for ridge regression where the degrees of freedom are not well defined. See for instance [Dijkstra 2014 Ridge regression and its degrees of freedom](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11135-013-9949-7)

You can still get $R^2$ by computing

$$R^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_{residuals}}{SS_{total}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You can get R2 just typing
lasso.reg$dev.ratio

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Note that `lasso.reg` here isn't itself an object of the `elnet` class, though it contains one - so `lasso.reg$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio`. It's better to explain your answers rather than make bare assertions.

Answer (score 0):

The R2 score can be calculated with below code,

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

pred_train_ridge= ridge.predict(X_train)
print("The Train R2 score for Ridge is ", r2_score(y_train, pred_train_ridge))
```